# Error creating the GCE VMs or starting Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm getting the following error in the recent jobs I'm trying to submit:

```
2015-01-07T15:51:56.404Z: (893c24e7fd2fd6de): Workflow failed. 
Causes: (893c24e7fd2fd601):    
   There was a problem creating the GCE VMs or starting Dataflow on the VMs so no data was processed.  Possible causes:
  1. A failure in user code on in the worker.
  2. A failure in the Dataflow code.
Next Steps:
  1. Check the GCE serial console for possible errors in the logs.
  2. Look for similar issues on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.
```

There are no other errors.

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the trouble.

The Dataflow starts up VM instances and then launches an agent on those VMs. Those agents then do the heavy lifting of executing your code (e.g. ParDo's, reading and writing) your Data.

The error indicates the job failed because no agents were requesting work. As a result, the service marked the job as a failure because it wasn't making any progress and never would since there weren't any agents to process your data.

So we need to figure out where in the agent startup process things failed.

The first thing to check is whether the VMs actually started. When you run your job do you see any VMs created in your project? It might take a minute or two for the VMs to startup but they should appear shortly after the runner prints out the message "Starting worker pool setup". The VMs should be named something like

```
<PREFIX-OF-JOB-NAME>-<TIMESTAMP>-<random hexadecimal number>-<instance number>
```

Only a prefix of the job name is used to ensure we don't exceed GCE name limits.

If the VMs startup the next thing to do is to inspect the worker logs to look for errors indicating problems in launching the agent.

The easiest way to access the logs is using the UI. Go to the Google Cloud Console and then select the Dataflow option in the left hand frame. You should see a list of your jobs. You can click on the job in question. This should show you a graph of your job. On the right side you should see a button "view logs". Please click that. You should then see a UI for navigating the logs and you can look for errors.

The second option is to look for the logs on GCS. The location to look for is:

```
gs://PATH TO YOUR STAGING DIRECTORY/logs/JOB-ID/VM-ID/LOG-FILE
```

You might see multiple log files. The one we are most interested in is the one that starts with "start_java_worker". If that log file doesn't exist then the worker didn't make enough progress to actually upload the file; or else there might have been a permission problem uploading the log file.

In that case the best thing to do is to try to ssh into one of the VMs before it gets torn down. You should have about 15 minutes before the job fails and the VMs are deleted.

Once you login to the VM you can find all the logs in

```
/var/log/dataflow/...
```

The log we care most about at this point is:

```
/var/log/dataflow/taskrunner/harness/start_java_worker-SOME ID.log
```

If there is a problem starting the code that runs on the VM that log should tell us. That log and the other logs should also tell us if there is a permission problem that prevents the code running on the worker from being able to access Dataflow.

Please take a look and let us know if you find anything.

Comment: The VMs are launched correctly and the error is reported after 10-15 minutes. I'll check the logs.

Comment: I see no errors in the log. I do see java processes running on the instances. Checking one of them I see it's doing this:     at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$DataflowWorkUnitClient.getWorkItem(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:184)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:94)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness.processWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:101)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness.main(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:96)

Comment: This looks like a support desk conversation, not an actual answer/solution. Can you confirm? Also, you should disclose your affiliation in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Jeremy Lewi's great answer, I would like to add that I've seen this error appear when you don't enable the proper Google APIs in the Developers Console, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/getting-started#APIs), which leads to a permission issue, like Jeremy said.